# How do I update CiviCRM following a security update?

Tags: security, upgrade

I am getting a warning to update security. It says:

> New security release 4.7.9 is available. The site is currently
>   running 4.7.3.

How do I update it?

Thanks.

Melissa
Brooklyn Commons
commonsbrooklyn.org

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I should say that this is a job for someone who is reasonably technically minded and comfortable with using the command line.  If this doesn't sound like you, then I would suggest that you look for help with this - perhaps from the person that installed CiviCRM in the first place.

You can find detailed instructions in the [Administrator Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/).  There are different versions depending on which CMS you use:

- [Upgrading CiviCRM for Drupal 7](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/drupal7/)
- [Upgrading CiviCRM for WordPress](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/)
- [Upgrading CiviCRM for Joomla](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/joomla/)

See also my question on upgrading with drush (Drupal only):

[Is it easy to upgrade CiviCRM using drush?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/is-it-easy-to-upgrade-civicrm-using-drush)

I would strongly recommend that you take a full backup before you do this.  You should also know how to restore from a backup in case anything goes wrong (which does happen unfortunately and can leave your site completely broken).

I would also recommend that you test the update on a development server before you attempt to update the live website.

If none of this makes any sense to you I think you should probably look for help from someone who has this technical knowledge - e.g. a [CiviCRM partner](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors).  Unfortunately, upgrading CiviCRM is not a simple one-click operation like upgrading WordPress.

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the steps in the link one by one

Link: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7#UpgradingCiviCRMforDrupal7-1.DownloadthemostrecentCiviCRMPackage

I guess this helps !!!