# How to install a security update

Tags: security-advisory

I need to upload the recent security update to CiviCrm 4.6.15, but I do not know how to or where to go to do same.  I tried under extensions update but it did not work.

Comment: See this related question: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/13154/how-do-i-update-civicrm-following-a-security-update

Answer (score 2):

The Wiki has good instructions for each CMS:

- [Upgrading CiviCRM for Drupal 7](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7)
- [Upgrading CiviCRM for Drupal 6](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+6)
- [Upgrading CiviCRM for WordPress](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+WordPress)
- [Upgrading CiviCRM for Joomla](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Joomla)

If you are using Drupal/drush, you may also be interested in [this thread](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/is-it-easy-to-upgrade-civicrm-using-drush).