# How do I perform a security update

Tags: security, upgrade

When logging on today, I got the following alert:

"Jmanage Security Update Required
New security release 4.7.11 is available. The site is currently running 4.7.9."

What steps do I need to perform to achieve this goal?

Comment: Please see my answer to the related question: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/13156/127

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your CMS - Here is the link https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installation+and+Upgrades
Always backup first - 
It is kind of like doing an instal except you do not need to do the configuration after :-)